# Draw double top/bottom lines with different line width in table

Tags: tables

There is a table draw with excel. How to copy it in `\LaTeX` code? The difficulty is at the top line and bottom line, which are double lines with different line width. 
[image]

Comment: Consider using the `booktabs` package, which gives you `\toprule[ wd ]`, `\midrule[ wd ]`, and `\bottomrule[ wd ]`. You can give rules whatever thickness you desire. (Wield that power with care.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  {\setlength\doublerulesep{0.4pt}   %%<-- sep between consecutive rules, begin group
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \toprule[1pt]\midrule[0.3pt]
    Here & there & where \\\cmidrule{2-3}
         & some  & thing \\ \midrule
    1  & 2  & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6  \\
    3 & 4 & 6 \\\midrule[0.3pt]\bottomrule[1pt]
  \end{tabular}
  }  %% end group for \doublerulesep so that effect is local
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the sake of consistency, you can define a newcommand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\dtoprule}{\specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{0.4pt}%
            \specialrule{0.3pt}{0pt}{\belowrulesep}%
            }
\newcommand{\dbottomrule}{\specialrule{0.3pt}{0pt}{0.4pt}%
            \specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{\belowrulesep}%
            }

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \dtoprule
    Here & there & where \\\cmidrule{2-3}
         & some  & thing \\ \midrule[0.5pt]
    1  & 2  & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6  \\
    3 & 4 & 6 \\\dbottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```